# Focus on module in intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I have Java project with a main pom and a number of sub project. Each time I work it's on a specific sub project so I would like to focus the workspace on that project by focus i mean : to only see files related to this project, and when i start a terminal to have it start with the project root as current path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your project window(which shows file structure), on top right you will see settings icon. Try selecting `Autoscroll to Source`

This will navigate to files you are working on automatically.